# Recursively add strings in an array together? (a triangle-number like function with strings)

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I'm playing with a simple "breadcrumb" nav in Rails and I want to split my current path into a series of strings. Yes I know there are libraries for this, but I am interested in how you would pull the following task off in pure Ruby.

Let's say you have a url path string like this:

```
/users/admins/1/edit
```

And you want to return an array of strings like this:

```
["/users","/users/admins","users/admins/1","users/admins/1/edit"]
```

How would you go about doing so? I've tried to use the `each_index` functions to add each subsequent portion together and shove it in a new array, but I can never get a true recursive addition of the strings.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
str = "/users/admins/1/edit"
str.split('/').drop(1).reduce([]){|res,s| res << res.last.to_s+'/'+s}
#=> ["/users", "/users/admins", "/users/admins/1", "/users/admins/1/edit"]
```

Second variant inspired by pguardiario

```
str.scan(/\/\w*/).reduce([]){|res,s| res << res.last.to_s + s}
```

Comment: This is awesome! I had never seen the "reduce" method before. Clever as hell

Answer (score 4):

Not really recursive, but does what you want:

```
a = '/users/admins/1/edit'.split('/')
a.each_index.map{|i| a[0..i].join('/')}[1..-1]

=> ["/users", "/users/admins", "/users/admins/1", "/users/admins/1/edit"]
```

Comment: A slight variation: `(2 .. a.length).map { |i| a[0,i].join('/') }`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe scan is a little cleaner than split:

```
paths = str.scan /\/\w*/
paths.length.times.map{|i| paths[0..i].join}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def split_paths(str)
  arr = []
  str.scan('/') {arr << $` unless $`.empty?}
  arr << str
  arr
end

split_paths('/users/admins/1/edit') # => ["/users", "/users/admins", "/users/admins/1", "/users/admins/1/edit"]
```